# Is every local quasi-finite morphism finite?

Tags: commutative-algebra, localization

Let $A\to B$ be a finite morphism, $(A,\mathfrak m)$ be a local ring, and $\mathfrak n$ be a maximal ideal of $B$ lying over $\mathfrak m$. Is there an example such that $A\to B_{\mathfrak n}$ is not finite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $R\to S^{-1}R$ integral $\implies$ $S\subseteq U(R)$.

If $A\to B_{\mathfrak n}$ is finite then $B\to B_{\mathfrak n}$ is integral, and therefore $B-\mathfrak n\subseteq U(B)$, so $\bigcup_{\mathfrak n'\in\text{Max}(B)} \mathfrak n'\subseteq \mathfrak n$. If $B$ is not local this is impossible. Now I leave you the pleasure to find a concrete example.

Comment: We have $A\to B_m\to B_n$, the first map is finite, we want to know if the second map is finite, that is, if every $B_m-n_m$ is invertible in $B_m$. I think it is true if $B$ is $C[[X,Y,Z]]$

Comment: I  trying to understand a definition of Henselian local ring: $A$ is Henselian if  every quasi-finite local homomorphism is finite..

Comment: I think using your criteria, the localization at ramification points of curves will give an counter example.Still I need to think why it is true for Henselian rings..